# Why is my account not allowed to ask questions?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, post-ban

Why is my account not allowed to ask questions?

May I know the reasons?
Where can I complain regarding this issue?

Whenever I tap to submit questions It shows "We are no longer accepting questions from this account."

Answer (score 4):

Your account is blocked from asking questions because you have a history of asking questions which are heavily downvoted and then closed and deleted. The system has already messaged you with a link to the help center, but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) it is again.

If you are confused about why your questions were so poorly received, consider reading one of the many closure messages on your questions. Ignoring these guidelines is what caused this situation.

Comment: Actually this is very old on that time I didn't the way to ask a good question? How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Seriously, you need to *actually read* the help center page that I linked. It directly answers that question.